# how to display different data type values with same variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

*Issue:*

When I am using same variable to hold different data types in java script, 
and trying to display all values, it is not showing up all values except the last value which it holds. is there any alternate way to show up all data type values with same variable?

*Script:*

```
<script>
var x; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
x = 5;               
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
x = "John";         
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

*Expected result:*

undefined
5
John

*Actual result:*

John

Comment: Basically js does not allow shadowing

Answer (score 3):

```js
    var x;                   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + ' ';
    x = 5;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + ' ';
    x = "John";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + ' ';
```

```html
<div id="demo"> </div>
```

Every time you set the innerHTML your overwriting what was there you need to add to it like below.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is getting the different values assigned correctly but you are showing all three instances inside the same DOM element. Each time you assign it, the current value overwrites the last value. And it is happening so fast, that you only see the last one ("John").

Why don't you put each one in a different DOM element?

```
var x;                   
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
x = 5;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
x = "John";
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on Scath answer but i can´t comment.

Like the others said you are replacing de content, you should use concatenation.

But I would use br tag instead of '\n' to get the expected result.

```
<script>
    var x;                   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x+ '<br/>';
    x = 5;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x+ '<br/>';
    x = "John";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x+ '<br/>';
</script>
```